# Is Physics2D.BoxCast a safe alternative to a row of raycasting?

Tags: unity, unityscript, raycasting

Raycasting in rows is a common practice.

1. Is using the Physics 2D BoxCast function a good alternative to using
   multiple raycasts spread out (an example use being collision
   detection in a custom character controller script)?
2. There is limited documentation on boxcasting. Would boxcasting be
   too intensive or more friendly to call each frame?

Comment: An explanation of the parameters; Origin: The point in space for the box to be created around.

Size: A Vector2 containing the width and height of a box. (The box streches out from the origin equal to one half of x and one half of y in their respective directions)

Angle: A float containing how much the box should be rotated on the origin.

Direction: A Vector2 specifying the direction to "drag" the box along. (The x and y are used to create the slope of a line, and the direction is the angle of that slope.)

The rest of the parameters are well explained on Unity's scripting reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Box cast would probably be more performant since it's only checking 4 vertices but it'll definitely be more accurate, at least depending on what you want. Good idea!

Example use:

```
RaycastHit2D raycast = Physics2D.BoxCast (

    //Starting point of box
    Vector2.zero,

    //Size of the box
    new Vector2 (2,2),

    //Angle of box,
    0f,

    //Direction to cast
    Vector2.right,

    //Distance to cast
    5f

);
```

This BoxCasts starting from Vector2d.zero with a square of length 2 in the direction of (0,1), for a distance of 5. Conceptually, this is like dragging a 2x2 square from (0,0) to (0,5) and detecting any collisions along the way.

Comment: The parameters explained here as an example are not consistent to that of [`Physics2D.BoxCast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.BoxCast.html)

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching me on that. I updated my answer with a more accurate explanation.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but the size is actually a vector 2--feel free to refer to my comment explaining the parameters

Comment: No, please, nitpick away. Thanks again for catching me :).